# ¿Como evitar múltiples usuarios registrados con el mismo e-mail?

Tags: php, mysql

Este es mi código entero  de la action que ejecuta el registro. Mi problema esta en la parte donde consulto la existencia del e-mail con que el usuario se quiere registrar,  ya que de acuerdo al código en caso de existir deberia enviarlo al formulario de registro nuevamente, en lugar de eso permite registrar múltiples usuarios con el mismo e-mail.  Aquí colocare el código completo, y un poco mas abajo, solo la sección que específicamente hace la consulta de la existencia del e-mail para que no la tengan que buscar.

Nota: Estoy aprendiendo a programar, por eso mi código esta lleno de comentarios de pensamientos que he tenido para ayudarme a entender lo que estoy haciendo, la información comentada puede no ser acertada (en caso de que alguien busque esta pregunta y la trate de usar como guía)

---

```
 <?php
 session_start ();
 /*Checar si el usuario reeaaalmente clicko el submit button y entonces que corra el script
 una medida de seguridad en caso de que un usuario decida ir dentro del sitio web y que cambie la url
 a "signup.inc.php" y vea todo el codigo. El boton es necesario para que corra este documento*/


 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
/* Isset: Checar si algo existe dentro de este archivo
Verificar si se envio (osea post) el submit, si fue apretado
"Determina si una variable está definida y no es NULL"*/

/*tomara nuestro datos del formulario anterior, que pasamos los valores usando un metodo post
y checara por un nombre llamado submit, y si vamos al signup.php form, el boton llamado tiene de nombre
submit, checa si el boton realmente ha sido presionado*/
{

                    /*Si presiono el boton, pasa esto*/

    include_once 'dbh.inc.php'; /*llamamos a la base de datos que hice antes*/

    /*Ahora sigue conseguir los verdaderos datos de php*/

    $first= mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST ['first']);
    $last= mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST ['last']);
    $email= mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST ['email']);
    $uid= mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST ['uid']);         
    $pwd= mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST ['pwd']); 
    $tarjeta= mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST ['tarjeta']); 

    /* la funcion de arriba antes de post, es para convertir lo que escriba en el input en texto.
    Esto se hace por si alguien escribe codigos en el input para alterar algo*/


        /*--------Para lidiar con un par de errores, cuenta como validacion?-----*/
        /*INVESTIGAR: ERROR HANDLERS, de los campos que necesite*/

        /*Checar por si hay cuadros vacios*/
        if (empty($first) || empty($last) || empty($email) || empty($uid) || empty($pwd) || empty($tarjeta))  /* || = "or", le estoy diciendo que si esa variable, aquella,
                                                    esta o la otra, alguna esta vacia, ejecutar el codigo que puse,*/
        {
            header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=empty"); /*Si esta algun campo vacio, lo devuelvo a signup*/
            exit(); /* por si algo pasa*/
        }

        else  /*Con "IF" checo si hay espacios vacios y ahora, si realmente estan llenos, con else, checo
        si es informacion que quiero en la base de datos.*/

        {
            /* Checar si los caracteres introducidos en input, son validos*/
            if (!preg_match ("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", $first) || !preg_match ("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", $last) ){ /* preg_match checa si tengo cierto caracteres dentro de un string*/
                                /* dentro de las comillas le digo que caracteres quiero, basicamente el digo si la variable first
                                tiene las letras que yo quiero. El signo de exclamacion le dice si hay characteres que NO son esos*/

                                header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=invalid"); /*Si esta algun campo vacio, lo devuelvo a signup, "invalid" es el error que le mando*/
                                exit(); /* por si algo pasa*/                                   
                                }

            else
            /* Checar si el e-mail es valido*/
            /* el signo de exclamacion es para que haga lo contrario a lo que le pido, en este caso
            vea si no es valido, sin el signo de exclamacion, checaria si es valido.*/
                if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=email"); /*Si esta algun campo vacio, lo devuelvo a signup, "invalid" es el error que le mando*/
                                exit(); /* por si algo pasa*/}

                else { /*Ahora a ver si el ID o nick ya no esta en uso*/


                /*Seleccionamos de la bd users, la tabla user_id
                y si hay algun nick alli igual al que metio este usuario
                ejecuta el comando que le dare*/

                $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_email = $email";
                /* Esto es solo para abreviar el codigo y llamarlo luego, por si mismo no hace nada*/

                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                /* A traves de query es que se le pregunta a la base de dato*/

                /* A traves de num rows */
                $resultcheck = mysql_num_rows ($result); /* este comando de mysql si no lo entendi bien, debo seguir investigando*/

                if ($resultcheck > 0) { header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=emailtaken"); 
                                exit(); /* por si algo pasa*/}

                    else {



                        if (strlen($tarjeta) == 16) {
                        // Lo que tengas que hacer con los datos recibidos
                                                    /* Insertar al usuario en la base de datos*/
                        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (user_nombre, user_apellido, user_email, user_nick, user_pwd, user_tarjeta) VALUES ('$first', '$last', '$email', '$uid', '$pwd', '$tarjeta')";
                        mysqli_query ($conn, $sql);                     
                        header("Location: ../index.php?signup=success");
                                                    exit ();

                        } else {
                        // Algún mensaje indicando que son necesarios 16 caracteres exactamente
                        header("Location: ../index.php?signup=notenoughcharacters");
                            }                                                       





                    }

                }

        }

    $first = $_POST['first']; /*'first' por que es la primera cosa que pide signup.php*/                
}


 else 
{
    header ("Location: ../index.php"); /*Si hay un espacio entre los dos puntos y "location" no funcionara*/
    exit (); /*Detiene el scrip de correr si hay algo despues del boton exit*/
}


 /*----------------------------- SIGN UP---------------------------------------------*/
```

---

```
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_email = $email";


                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);



                $resultcheck = mysql_num_rows ($result); 

                if ($resultcheck > 0) { header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=emailtaken"); 
                                exit();}

                    else { }
```

---

Y no entiendo por que sucede esto si mientras testeaba eso, funciono completamente

```
$dbServername = "localhost"; 
$dbUsername = "root";   
$dbPassword = "";   
$dbName = "loginsystem2";

$conn = mysqli_connect ($dbServername, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName ); 



$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = '1'";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql); /* debe ser mysqli (con i) */

$resultcheck = mysqli_num_rows ($result);





if ($resultcheck > 0)
{
echo 'funka';
}


else

{
    echo 'no funka';
}
```

Comment: no sería mas simple para evitar duplicidad que la columna email directo en tu base de datos fuera UNIQUE ?

Comment: La query compara con un texto, cuidado con las comillas "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_email='".$email."' ".

Comment: Al final, el funcionó pero fue algo distinto el resultado, termino siendo 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_email = '.$email' ";

Con comillas simples y el punto antes de la variable, aunque es primera vez que añado el punto antes de la variable para que funcione una linea de codigo, no estoy seguro bajo que condiciones se hace esto o son necesarias para que funcione. Gracias por la ayuda !

Answer (score 2):

El problema está en esta parte del código, tu la tienes asi:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_email = $email";
```

Pero debería ser así:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_email = '$email'";
```

Pon mucha atencion a este tipo de fallos porque producen errores a la hora de ejecutarse y son difíciles de encontrar si estas empezando!

Comment: Lo intente y no funcionó, al final lo resolví y el resultado termino siendo este 

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_email = '.$email' ";  efectivamente debia estar entre las comillas simples pero tambien era necesario el punto antes de la variable, aunque no estoy seguro de por que y cuando usarlo de esta manera. Gracias por la ayuda !

Comment: @Hoozuki si lo escribes exactamente así `$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_email = '$email'";` debería funcionar, pues es lo mismo que: `$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_email = '".$email.'";` Pero sería importante que entiendas el núcleo del asunto, que es muy sencillo. Cuando se tratan valores alfanuméricos estos deben ir entre comillas simples  `'` y cuando se tratan valores numéricos estos deben ir sin nada. Lo digo porque veo en tu código otra consulta con el `id` aplicando lo que deberías aplicar con los alfanuméricos. Por otra parte tu código es vulnerable a inyección SQL.

Comment: Raro, no me funciona, quizás es por que estoy usando una versión mas vieja de php?  Lo seguire intentando con ese metodo a ver, gracias. Y si hablas de la consulta del ultimo codigo donde  arrojo un echo de "funka" o "no funka", eso fue solamente para probar la función mysqli_num_rows y experimentar con ella para entenderla, no va a ser usada en la pagina.